# Java How to store a complex string to Map

Tags: java

I have a string that is like this:

ab1234, 'This is book 1'; c56789, 'This is book 2'; d0123, 'This is book 3';

As you can it is a key value pair between the first and second element, which themselves are separated by a comma and each pair is separated by a semi-colon.

What I am trying to do is place these pairs into a HashMap, but not being that familiar with Java, and not too sure what is the best practice.

I have seen that it to turn each part into an array, thus:

```
  String[] arrayOne = complexString.split(";");
  String[] arrayTwo = arrayOne.split(",");
```

Can someone please advise which is the best way to do this?

Comment: `split` works on strings. Not on array of strings. You will have to do the second split in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split each string in your first array in loop. The following code will do it. You should be sure data is always as described, and you may do something to get rid off single quotes in your data if necessary.

```
String[] arrayOne = complexString.split(";");
for(String str : arrayOne) {
   String[] pair = str.split(",");
   map.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. So, I was almost there. Yes, the data will be as described because I am passing data via a React application where I am adding the single quotes,  comma and semi colon. Therefore, there will never be a comma or semi colon out of place

Comment: @Andy5 happy that I could help. You might accept it an answer if it was enough to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the approach based on calling `split` is separators embedded in values of strings, for example

```
ab1234, 'This ; is book 1'; c56789, 'This ; is, book 2';
//            ^                           ^   ^
```

`split` function does not care if a separator is inside quoted string or not, so you will end up with broken keys and values.

Fortunately, writing a parser for this kind of input is really straightforward: all you need to do is scanning the input character-by-character, while paying attention to entering and exiting quoted regions.

You can also use regular expressions to match the following pattern:

```
\s*(?<key>[^,]+),\s*'(?<value>[^']*)'\s*;
```

and harvest groups called `"key"` and `"value"` from it:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?<key>[^,]+),\\s*'(?<value>[^']*)'\\s*;");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
while (m.find()) {
    String key = m.group("key");
    String val = m.group("value");
    ...
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/nrhgCy)

Answer (score 0):

I like the regex approach for cases like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

String input = "ab1234, 'This is book 1'; c56789, 'This is book 2'; d0123, 'This is book 3';";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*?),(.*?);").matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
    String key = m.group(1);
    String value = m.group(2);
    map.put(key.trim(), value.trim()); // trim optional
}

for(String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key: " + key);
    System.out.println("Value: " + map.get(key));
}
```

It prints:

```
Key: ab1234
Value: 'This is book 1'
Key: c56789
Value: 'This is book 2'
Key: d0123
Value: 'This is book 3'
```

**Be careful with commas or semicolons inside the 'values'**